# Google Admob not displaying ads using cordova tabset example?

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-admob

I'm using the basic admob example to display banner ads on my cordova app but either no ads appear or they may be appearing but occluded by another window.

Here's the example code I'm using:

```html
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
   var ad_units = {
       ios : {
           banner: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       },
       android : {
           banner: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       }
    };
       // select the right Ad Id according to platform
    var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;

    // Nothing happens.....                          
    if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( admobid.banner );

  });
})
```

Has anyone had experience with this or can suggest some ways to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the AdMob plugin in https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova and I suppose from your code that this is the one that you are using. If this is the case you have two options:

**1st:** replace `banner` by `publisherId` and `admobid.banner` by `admobid`. Also for testing purposes you should set `isTesting` to `true` in order to prevent your account being blocked by Google:

```
var ad_units = {
   ios : {
       publisherId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       isTesting: true
   },
   android : {
       publisherId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       isTesting: true
   }
};

// select the right Ad Id according to platform
var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;                        
if (AdMob) {
  AdMob.createBanner(admobid);
}
```

**2nd:** You should declare `.banner` as an object with ads configuration inside:

```
var ad_units = {
   ios : {
     banner: {
       publisherId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       isTesting: true
     }
   },
   android : {
     banner: {
       publisherId: 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/2259066653',
       isTesting: true
     }
   }
};

// select the right Ad Id according to platform
var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;                       
if (AdMob) {
  AdMob.createBanner(admobid.banner);
}
```

Also with Ionic I've tested it with `ionic.Platform.ready(function () { ... });` instead of `$ionicPlatform`. Otherwise, in order to prevent errors if the code is minified, Angular recommends using it in this way (but it should not affect if you are not minifying the code):

```
app.run(['$ionicPlatform', function ($ionicPlatform) {
  ...
}]);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem as OP's. Could you provide a simple fiddle about run/config settings in an Ionic app, and how to create/show banner in states/pages ?

Comment: @IsmailKuruca there is a [great tutorial here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps)